# How can I create a variable in php that exists after refresh?

Tags: php, page-refresh

ok watch to this simple code

```
<h1><?php echo $a ?></h1>
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="foo">
<input type="submit">
<?php
if(!(empty($_POST['foo']))){
     $a = $_POST['foo'];
}
?>
</form>
```

Here I want to save value of input into $a variable, but the problem is that when user is pushing the submit button the page is refreshing and the variable $a does not exist anymore. So how can be created variable in php that is not deleting every time refreshing ;)

Comment: Sessions are what you're looking for.

Comment: Use session variables. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Answer (score 0):

When you submit your form (what you call refresh :)), you input-data will be sent to the url which is stored in the `action` attribute of your `form` element. If there is no `action` attribute, the form-data will be submitted to the page itself (this is the case with in example).

To receive the submitted value you have to set `$a` to you submitted value **before** you output it. So just move the setting code to the top of your script.

Example:

```
<?php
$a = ''; // default value
// if(!(empty($_POST['foo']))) {

// Better:
if(isset($_POST) && array_key_exists('foo', $_POST)) { // check if $_POST exists AND if it holds a key `foo`
     $a = $_POST['foo'];
}
?>
<h1><?php echo $a ?></h1>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="foo">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Be careful what you output on your page. You want to sanitize user-input (aka. only allow content you intent to get submitted). In this case it is possible to submit HTML or JavaScript, which may destroy the layout of your page. To prevent this you can use `htmlspecialchars` ([example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php#refsect1-function.htmlspecialchars-examples)).

Furthermore, you may dont want to output the `<h1>...</h1>` in case its empty anyways. To accomplish this you can wrap your html like this:

```
<?php
if (strlen($a) > 0) {
?>
    <h1><?= htmlspecialchars($a) ?></h1>
<?php
}
?>
```

OR

```
<?php
if (strlen($a) > 0) {
    echo '<h1>' . htmlspecialchars($a) . '</h1>';
}
?>
```

### Alternative - ([filter_input](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php))

This way you dont have to check `$_POST` at all. If there is no `foo` in `$_POST`, this function will return `null`.

```
<?php
    $a = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'foo', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
?>
```